# How to return a value from `component` class?

Tags: angular, angular7

I need the constructor with a class, as well need to `return` value. I am sending the value to router. in case if i keep my code like this, it works:

```
export function getAdalConfig() {
    return {
        tenant: 'xxxx.onmicrosoft.com',
        clientId: 'sdff-9be4-5a107f67fedb',
        redirectUri: window.location.origin,
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        expireOffsetSeconds: 600,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin
    };
}
```

if I change to class declartion like this, not working. How to handle this?

```
export class AdalConfig implements OnInit {
    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit(){

       this.sendConfig();
    }

    sendConfig() {

        return {
            tenant: 'xxxx.onmicrosoft.com',
            clientId: 'sdff-9be4-5a107f67fedb',
            redirectUri: window.location.origin,
            navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
            cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
            expireOffsetSeconds: 600,
            postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin
        };
    }
}
```

usage of above function is like this:

```
 MsAdalAngular6Module.forRoot(AdalConfig),
```

So how to return like function using the class declaration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MsAdalAngular6Module.forRoot(new AdalConfig().sendConfig()) Maybe? It is not really clear what are you trying to achieve. Could you give more details into the context of it,

Comment: this is just matter of passing config data to root. i need to get the confirg from the store. so i requires the constructor. as a simple i am trying to behave my class like function